# Horizontal and Vertical centered card on bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i'm having troubles centering a card (or container). I'm able to center it horizontally but not vertically. I alredy tested some code found on stack and other webpages but it does not seems to work.
My current code is:

```
<div class="container col-md-3 py-5">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h3 class="mb-0">Login</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <form class="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">Username:</label> <input  class="form-control" type="text" name="username" id="username" autofocus required >
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password: </label> <input class="form-control" type="password" name="user" id="password" required>
                </div>
             </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe below code should work for you, just try and check

```
.container.py-5{
    position: absolute; //or relative
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: should i eddit the container.py boostrap class or how should i add it?

Comment: just put this code in your css file and see if it works for you

Comment: Okay i've just created a css with a subclass for container and worked.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help

Answer (score 1):

[TESTED - working] Use flexbox. 
https://www.bootply.com/AaDqw82aFL#

Wrap your code with additional div with class containing following two style rules.

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center; 
align-conten:center; 
min-height: 100%;  /* Fallback for browsers do NOT support vh unit */
min-height: 100vh;
```

It should work fine.

Full code with inline style (I recommend you to use class instead of `style` attribute):

```
  <div style=" display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center; align-conten:center; min-height: 100%;  /* Fallback for browsers do NOT support vh unit */min-height: 100vh;">
  <div class="container col-md-3 py-5" style="height: 200px; width:200px">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h3 class="mb-0">Login</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <form class="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="username">Username:</label> <input class="form-control" type="text" name="username" id="username" autofocus="" required="">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="password">Password: </label> <input class="form-control" type="password" name="user" id="password" required="">
                </div>
             </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Getting exactly the same result that i have with my code, just the margin of py-5 (and if i do not put py-5 it just is most topt with no margin)

Comment: Now it's fixed.

Comment: after removing that was avoiding a perfect centered it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Add `d-flex align-items-center` bootstrap4 classes on your `body` and put its height on `100vh;`

```css
body{
  height:100vh;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
<body class="d-flex align-items-center">
    <div class="container col-md-3 py-5">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="mb-0">Login</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <form class="form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="username">Username:</label> <input  class="form-control" type="text" name="username" id="username" autofocus required >
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="password">Password: </label> <input class="form-control" type="password" name="user" id="password" required>
                    </div>
                 </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```